# Positioning elements on background image

Tags: css, background-image

I have a viewport-filling container (main) with a background image (background-size: cover).

I need to position another element (article) i.e. on the right eye (pov) of the cat.

the problem: because of the background size, the image varies in size if the browser is resized and the positioning of the article has to be flexible.

is there a good way to do that?

```css
 body, html {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
    }

main {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/562933c2e4b09e3e7576aa26/t/57a8cf2b440243645807818b/1470680877891/katze-begruessen.jpg?format=2500w) no-repeat;
     background-position: top center;
     background-size: cover;
     overflow: scroll;
      }
article {
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      background: yellow;
      }
```

```html
<main>
  <article></article>
</main>
```

Comment: how about using multiple background? have your tried it?

Comment: It's not possible to achieve that. In addition, it's generally a bad thing to build parts of a website based on an image, unless the design is absolutely static.

Comment: @Manjunath in which way would that help?

Comment: @Alex Vand Yes it's a bad thing and a bad idea but well... here I am. I don'T think it's impossible – there has to be at least a tacky javascript solution...

Comment: @bstnhnsl i think I miss read the question,my bad :D , but you can do one thing, you can specify background size fixed based on device break points and positioning  of bg.

Comment: Don't use a **background** image - use an **actual** image - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dgcha